# Have server download file from users Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm developing an Android app that lets users upload files from their Google Drive using Google Drive Android API. Instead of having users download the file to the device and then upload it to my server, I would like to generate a download link which the user can post to the server and have it download the file directly from the Google Drive API.

Is this possible in any way? The only way I can think of is having the user authenticate in both the app and through a browser window, but that is quite a hassle for something that seems like a pretty common use case.

Comment: @noogui Yes. Please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38109036/google-drive-android-api-and-cross-client-authorization

Answer (score 0):

**I would like to generate a download link..and have it download the file directly from the Google Drive API.**

This is certainly doable and I've tried it. Try this tutorial on [Creating Direct Links From Drive](http://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/). Just take note of your file type- doc, ppt, img ,etc. and the corresponding FILE ID.

```
For Google Docs files:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/FILE_ID/export?format=doc 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/FILE_ID/export?format=pdf

For Google Presentations files:
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/FILE_ID/export/pptx 
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/FILE_ID/export/pdf

For Google Spreadsheets files:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/FILE_ID/edit?usp=sharing
```

Here's an SS of a direct download I got using the pptx format.

[image]