# Google Drive Android API and Cross Client Authorization

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, android-googleapiclient

I use Google Drive Android API for letting users upload files from Google Drive on their Android device to my servers.
I would now like to change this setup to allow my servers to have direct access to the users Google Drive, using Cross Client Authorization, which means that I have to generate an `ID Token` using `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken`. And this is were everything go off the rails. In order to generate this token I need an `Account` object.

Currently, I'm setting up the `GoogleApiClient` like this:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
    .addApi(Drive.API)
    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .build();
```

This works great, every now and then it shows an account picker where the user can choose what account to connect with. All managed by the framework. But there is no way to access the `Account` the user chose to connect with!

Instead, I have to manage it myself, using:

```
Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[]{"com.google"},
    false, null, null, null, null);
startActivityForResult(intent, RC_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
```

And in `onActivityResult` I can get the selected account using:

```
Account account = new Account(intent.getExtras().getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME),
    intent.getExtras().getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE));
```

And now, since I have an `Account` object, I can connect explicitly using that:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
    .addApi(Drive.API)
    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
    .setAccountName(mAccount.name) // Account name!
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .build();
```

Is this my only option, is there really no way to get the `Account` the user selected using my first solution?

--

Later on, when trying to generate my `ID Token` using:

```
String scope = String.format("oauth2:server:client_id:%s:api_scope:%s",
    "12345.apps.googleusercontent.com", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file");
String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getContext(), mAccount, scope);
```

I'm still getting an `UserRecoverableAuthException` where I need to be granted yet another permission from the user, even though I'm using the same account and the same auth scope as when I connect.
When all that is taken care of, I can run the same code again and finally get my `ID Token`.

--

Is there something I've fundamentally misunderstood or this is really how it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()` anymore as explained in [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/05/improving-security-and-user-experience.html) as it is unsafe to pass those tokens to your server.

Instead, you should use [Enable Server-Side Access](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access) via [Google Sign In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/) and use the [requestServerAuthCode() method](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInOptions.Builder).

This avoids double prompting the user, does not use the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission, and gives you a single user flow for logging in.

Comment: Can I ask a question? At the blog spot, `In general, you should NOT use GoogleAuthUtil.getToken, unless you are making REST API call on Android client.`, if I understand correctly, that means `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken` can still be used securely if the requests to REST API called directly on Android app (without any server)?

Comment: If you want to use an id token locally, you'd probably still want to use the [id token flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/migration-guide#migrate_to_the_id_token_flow) and use `requestIdToken()` to get the advantage of a single sign on.

Comment: I see, however, is `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken` still secured in this case? Moreover, id token only used for getting `user's ID, email address, name, or profile picture URL`, not for accessing other Google APIs, such as Google Drive, Youtube, or Contacts

Comment: Thank you, this is great! Is there any way to request an auth code without using the Sign In API, it's not a big deal but I don't need to know about a users basic info and profile, I just want them to access their Drive through my app.

Comment: If you use a blank `GoogleSignInOptions.Builder` (i.e., use the `new GoogleSignInOptions.Buidler()` constructor) then you won't get basic info and profile (you'd need to use `GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN` or specifically call `requestId()` and `requestProfile()` to do that)